# How does $\sigma(T)$ change with respect to $T$?

Tags: reference-request, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Consider $\sigma$ as a mapping which maps $T\in\mathcal{L}(X)$ to $\sigma(T)$, the spectrum of $T$, a compact set in the complex plane.

I wonder whether there is some result concerning how $\sigma(T)$ changes when $T$ changes. For instance,  how is the Hausdorff distance between $\sigma(T)$ and $\sigma(S)$ related to $\|T-S\|$? Or something like this.

Thanks!

Comment: This reference  may help http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/zm/zm22/zm2218.pdf, but it doesn't answer your question for arbitrary bounded operators.

Comment: @Norbert Thanks for the reference! It's helpful!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without assuming additional properties on $S$ and $T$, such as commutation or self-adjointness (on a Hilbert space) — see points 2. and 3. at the end of the answer — continuity of the spectrum as a map from $\mathcal{L}(X)$ to the compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ with the Hausdorff distance $d_H$ doesn't hold, because the spectrum can “collapse” under arbitrarily small perturbations, as illustrated by the following simple example:

Let $X = \ell^p(\mathbb{Z})$ with basis $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ and $1 \leq p \leq \infty$. Define the operator $S: X \to X$ by
$$
S(e_n) = e_{n-1}\text{ if }n\neq 0 \quad\text{and}\quad S(e_0) = 0.
$$
It is not difficult to check that $\sigma(S) = \overline{\mathbb{D}} = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\,:\,\lvert \lambda\rvert \leq 1\}$:  Indeed, $\lVert S \rVert = 1$, so we certainly have the inclusion $\sigma(S) \subset \overline{\mathbb{D}}$  and if $\lvert\lambda\rvert \lt 1$, the vector $v = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda^n e_n$ is an eigenvector of $S$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, so $\lambda \in \sigma(S)$. It follows from compactness of $\sigma(S)$ that $\sigma(S) \supset \overline{\mathbb{D}}$.

Let now $C$ be the rank one operator defined by $Ce_0 = e_{-1}$ and $C(e_n) = 0$ for $n \neq 0$. Putting $T_\varepsilon = S + \varepsilon C$ we have an invertible operator for $\varepsilon \neq 0$ and $\lVert T_{\varepsilon} - S\rVert = \varepsilon$.

For the spectral radius of $T_\varepsilon$ we have $r(T_{\varepsilon}) =1$, so $\sigma(T_{\varepsilon}) \subset \overline{\mathbb{D}}$. The inverse of $T_{\varepsilon}$ also has spectral radius $r(T_{\varepsilon}^{-1}) = 1$, so $\sigma(T_{\varepsilon}) \subset \partial\mathbb{D}$.

It follows from $\sigma(S) = \overline{\mathbb{D}}$ and $\sigma(T_\varepsilon) \subset \partial \mathbb{D}$ that the Hausdorff distance between $\sigma(S)$ and $\sigma(T_{\varepsilon})$ is at least $1$, while $\lVert S-T_{\varepsilon}\rVert = \varepsilon$ is as small as we wish.

---

**Added:** On the other hand, in some sense this is the worst that can happen: T. Kato, *[Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators](http://books.google.com/books?id=8ji2kN_D3BwC)*, Springer Classics in Mathematics, 1995, proves in §3, section 1. of chapter IV on [pp208f](http://books.google.com/books?id=8ji2kN_D3BwC&pg=PA208) the following:

1. The spectrum is *upper semicontinuous* as a function from $\mathcal{L}(X)$ to the compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ with respect to the Hausdorff distance (Remark 3.3).
2. If $S$ and $C$ commute then there is the estimate $d_{H}(\sigma(S),\sigma(S+C)) \leq r(C)$ on the Hausdorff distance of the spectra (Theorem 3.6).
3. **Much later:** To address a question posed in a comment: if $S$ and $T$ are self-adjoint operators on a Hilbert space then $d_H(\sigma(S),\sigma(T)) \leq r(S-T) = \lVert S - T \rVert$ holds as well, mainly because the resolvent satisfies $\lVert R_T(\lambda)\rVert = 1/d(\lambda,\sigma(T))$, which allows us to apply a variant of the [Neumann series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series), see Kato, [Theorem V.4.10](http://books.google.com/books?id=8ji2kN_D3BwC&pg=PA291), page 291 and [section II.1.3](http://books.google.com/books?id=8ji2kN_D3BwC&pg=PA66), in particular formula (1.13) on page 67. Far more precise results can be found at the beginning of  chapter VIII, especially §1.2.

The example above (which I learned from Edi Zehnder) appears as Example 3.8 on [page 210](http://books.google.com/books?id=8ji2kN_D3BwC&pg=PA210).

Comment: This (illuminating) example somewhat reminds me of the [ill-conditioning of the Jordan form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Numerical_analysis) in numerical linear algebra.

Comment: An illuminating example! But how would the property, say, commutation, change the situation?

Comment: @HuiYu: See edit.${}{}{}$

Comment: @t.b. Out of curiosity, why would the result be true for self-adjoint operators? How would one prove, say, that if $A_n \to A$ are (non-commuting and) self-adjoint then $d_H(\sigma(A_n), \sigma(A)) \to 0$?

Comment: @PZZ: you can prove that for s.a. operators you have $d_H(\sigma(A_n),\sigma(A)) \leq r(A_n-A)=\|A_n-A\|$ because the norm of the resolvent of a s.a. operator $B$ is $\|R_B(\lambda)\| = 1/d(\lambda,\sigma(B))$ which allows you to use a variant of the Neumann series. See Kato, [Thm V.4.10](http://books.google.com/books?id=8ji2kN_D3BwC&pg=PA291) on p.291 and also [section II.1.3](http://books.google.com/books?id=8ji2kN_D3BwC&pg=PA66), especially formula (1.13) on p.67. Much more precise results are in chapter VIII, especially 1.2.

Comment: @t.b. I approved an edit by an (your?) anonymous user. If this was not you, please roll it back. Sorry for the bother --

Comment: @draks: thank you! Yes, that was me... Now it finally worked :) cheers, t.